# I have a Sony Vaio SVT131Aiil. The wireless does not show up as an option in network manager

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, network-manager, atheros

I have no wireless connections. We recently switched our internet service provider and I cannot see the new wireless router/modem.  This is the output from the wireless info script:

```
    ======== Wireless-Info START ========
```

System-Info ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

sven 3.13.0-74-generic x86_64,  Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, trusty

CPU    : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory : 3835 MB
Uptime : 11:24:05 up 23:15,  2 users,  load average: 0.03, 0.12, 0.09

lspci ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Unex DHXA-225 [105b:e044]
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)

0e:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Device [104d:90a8]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

lsusb ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b328 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0489:e036 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:0018 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

PCMCIA Card Info ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

iwconfig ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

rfkill ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
  Interface               Soft blocked  Hard blocked
```

0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN        no            no
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth      no            no
2: hci0: Bluetooth                no            no

lsmod ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

wmi                    19177  0

module parameters ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

wmi           (2): debug_dump_wdg=N | debug_event=N

nm-tool ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

State: connected (global)
============================o=======o========o===========o=========o===========o==============o===========
 Interface & ID             | Type  | Driver | State     | Default | Speed     | Support      | HW Addr
============================o=======o========o===========o=========o===========o==============o===========
 eth0  [Wired connection 1] | Wired | r8169  | connected | yes     | 1000 Mb/s |              |

```
Address:         192.168.0.128
Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
Gateway:         192.168.0.1
DNS:             192.168.0.1
```

----------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------

NetworkManager.state ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

NetworkManager.conf ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

NM WiFi Profiles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

BU (802.1x)          : ssid=BU (802.1x) | mac-address= | ipv4=auto 
BU Guest (unencrypted) : ssid=BU Guest (unencrypted) | mac-address= | ipv6=auto | ipv4=auto 
cardboardcastle      : ssid=cardboardcastle | mac-address= | ipv4=auto | ipv6=auto 
Chromecast4211       : ssid=Chromecast4211 | mac-address= | ipv6=auto | ipv4=auto 
Costello             : ssid=Costello | mac-address= | ipv4=auto | ipv6=auto 
enfield              : ssid=enfield | mac-address= | ipv6=auto | ipv4=auto 
Pote House           : ssid=Pote House | mac-address= | ipv4=auto | ipv6=auto 
PUBLIC ACCESS        : ssid=PUBLIC ACCESS | mac-address= | ipv6=auto | ipv4=auto 
Redzone-C7F0         : ssid=Redzone-C7FO | ipv4=auto | ipv6=auto 
Rosebud              : ssid=Rosebud | mac-address= | ipv6=auto | ipv4=auto 
wallace              : ssid=wallace | mac-address= | ipv6=auto | ipv4=auto 
ZootCoffeeMobile     : ssid=ZootCoffeeMobile | mac-address= | ipv6=auto | ipv4=auto

interfaces ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

resolv.conf ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search netgear.com

Routes & Ping ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.514/0.525/0.536/0.011 ms

--- 127.0.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.059/0.062/0.065/0.003 ms

iw reg get ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

(Region : "en_US.UTF-8")

iwlist chan ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
       -
```

iwlist scan ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

blacklist ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist acer_wmi

modinfo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[wmi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-74-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/wmi.ko
srcversion:     CED5410F008DC70DF5F064B
depends:
parm:           debug_event:Log WMI Events [0/1] (bool)
parm:           debug_dump_wdg:Dump available WMI interfaces [0/1] (bool)

udev rules ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:0e:00.0 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

PCI device 0x168c:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0 (ath9k)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

Custom files/entries ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/etc/modules        : Not Default
/etc/rc.local       : Default
/etc/modprobe.d     : Not Default
/etc/pm/(cnf|pw|sl) : Default

[/etc/modules]
loop

[/etc/modprobe.d]
ath10k_core.conf  : options ath10k_core skip_otp=y
iwlwifi.conf      : remove iwlwifi \
                    (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
                    && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
mlx4.conf         : softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

Kernel boot line ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic root=UUID=bc1c1071-aa99-418e-b1c1-213195f04050 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7

dmesg ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[    0.654017] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 , Peter Oruba
[    0.654389] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    0.815525] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    3.844025] wmi: Mapper loaded
[    5.434947] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3

`======== Done ========</pre></code>`

I would really appreciate it if someone would tell me how to fix this.

ls | grep back; dkms status

backports-20150903
backath10k, 2.0, 3.13.0-74-generic, x86_64: installed

Comment: Please edit to include `ls | grep back; dkms status` thanks

Comment: You should upgrade your kernel. Before trying anything else, run 'sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need backports or the backath10k dkms I made for the AR9485 card to work.  So we will remove them

```
cd backports-20150903
sudo make uninstall
sudo dkms remove backath10k/2.0 --all
```

Reboot

After reboot your `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` should show

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Unex DHXA-225 [105b:e044]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```